# Why my vuejs app can not play audio from request?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amazon-s3, axios, html5-audio

I'm creating an music player application and I went to the following problem. In the `created` function I make a `GET` request to the server, which is response an song object with an AWS S3 bucket URL. Then I use the song object `trackPath` prop to init audio src, but the audio src does not play anything. It looks like the media source do not see anything, but when i check the HTML in dev mode, the html code is good, there is the link for the src prop. If i 'hardcode' an s3 link to the file to the audio src it works fine. Here is my code. What is the problem? I do not have any idea. I tried with beforeMount etc but does not work.

```js
<template>
  <div class="player">
      <audio controls preload="auto" class="audio-player">
      <source :src="getTrackPath()" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios'

import config from '../config'

export default {
  name: 'PlayerComponent',
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.$el)
  },
  created () {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

    axios.get(config.trackURL.concat(`?_id=${this.id}`), {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }).then((resp) => {
      this.song = resp.data[0]
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  },
  data () {
    return {
      song: {},
      id: this.$route.params.id
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getTrackPath () {
      return this.song.trackPath
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just FYI `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a header that needs to present on the server response. Adding this to the client request will not do anything.

Comment: Thanks! :) You're right..